# Getting the dreaded inconsistent $fotoramaElement.fotorama is not a function

Tags: requirejs, magento2.4, fotorama

I see quite a few people have this issue, but I can't find a solution that works. I have `app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/requirejs-config.js` and I have it shimed, but I'm getting the same error.

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'parallax': 'js/jquery.parallax.min',
        'sfowlcarousel': 'owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min',
        'owl.carousel_thumbs': 'owl.carousel/owl.carousel2.thumbs',
        'floatelement': 'js/jquery.floatelement',
        'sfs/stellar': 'js/jquery.stellar.min',
        'jquery/lazyload': 'js/jquery.lazyload',
        'fotorama/fotorama': 'fotorama/fotorama'
    },
    shim: {
        'fotorama/fotorama': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'parallax': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'sfowlcarousel': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'owlcarousel_thumbs': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'sfowlcarousel']
        },
        'floatelement': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'sfs/stellar': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'jquery/lazyload': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    },
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'mage/collapsible': {
                'js/collapsible-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an external script that was causing this. I'm still not sure why, but in my case it was a script from Constant Contact (yours may be different).

Instead of including it in the header scripts, I moved it into a block (not sure if that did anything) and then I added an async tag to that script. That seems to have done it.

To troubleshoot, remove all of your third party scripts and see if that makes $fotorama run consistently. If it does, add the scripts back slowly until you figure out which one is breaking $fotorama.

Add an async tag to that script, and it should work.

Example

```
<script async> var _ctct_m = "<my cc id>"; </script>
```